# Is it a bad practice to use pure lock() method in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#lock--):

> void lock()
> Acquires the lock.
> If the lock is not available then the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until the lock has been acquired.

I'm using timed tryLock nearly everywhere, handling all what is expected - if timout ends, if it is interrupted, and so on.

But today, I've thought: **is it bad/unsafe/dangerous to use pure lock()?**

*Examples showing it looking so cute and elegant - just lock and unlock in finally. I've googled, but haven't found answer about it being a bad practice.*

Comment: Where did you get the idea from that using `lock()` was a bad practice?

Comment: I'm just asking about it. For me, it looks much safer to use a timed lock - it prevents thread from being stuck. But there are bunch of examples all over the Internet filled with pure lock() calling. So, such situation caused this question.

Comment: When your thread never returns from `lock()`, the failure is on the other side never releasing the lock (in 99% of all cases). Even when having a true deadlock caused by trying to acquire a lock while holding another, using a timeout would only kludge at the symptoms as you’d be trading a deadlock for a failure to ever perform the operation. Any timeout value would be arbitrary here, the elapsed time doesn’t tell you whether you truly solved a liveness problem or just didn’t wait long enough.

Comment: I think no other way of locking is available.... so lock is used all the way around.  The thing probably is that it is a very low level way of locking, implementing just a simple mutex... if you want to use conditions or semaphores, you need to compose on this to make them available.

Comment: Luis Colorado, question is about very different. It's about if tryLock worser/better/stabler to use than pure lock. I do no what is locking in general. I DO no what is locking in general.

Comment: @Holger, "you’d be trading a deadlock for a failure to ever perform the operation" - yes, exactly, and I'm not sure if deadlock is better. So, asking a question

Comment: There is no point in assuming that every lock operation can lead to a deadlock. As said, if the other side is not releasing the lock, you should fix that. And avoid to attempt to acquire a lock when already holding a lock. In general, prefer to fix bugs instead of trying to recover from them, strive for correct application logic instead of trying to solve the problems at a low level (where they can’t be solved). Defensive coding has a limit. You shouldn’t prepend every member access with an `if(object != null)` nor prepend every division with `if(dividend != 0)`, etc.

Comment: I see. I'm usually sure in logic, using tryLock is just a habit, that prevents me from deadlocks. Holger, can you combine those comments into an answer? I'd be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you use it inside of your code. If you just use it, only for lock and unlock, then you don't use any of the features it provides. So, you can merely fallback to intrinsic locks using the keyword synchronized. However, if you use timed lock and interruptible locking facilities, then it may be reasonable given your specific usecase warrants it. Intrinsic locks still have significant advantages over explicit locks. The notation is familiar and compact. Oftentimes, developers forget to call unlock on explicit locks, making it much more prone to errors.

Moreover, if you use condition objects you can still use either of them. If you have only one condition for the lock object, I would rather use intrinsic locks. The explicit locks become handy when you need to have multiple conditions for a given lock and need to use it without any interference from other conditions on the same lock.

In conclusion, it all depends on how you use it and whether your usecase warrants it.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to say if its bad or good. If you need to handle critical blocks, you need to lock it.